# grep is not working inside while loop

Tags: grep

I have two files

File1

---

```
area a 
area b 
areaf
```

File2

---

```
area a :aaaa
area b:bbbb
area3:abc
areaf:hsg
area4:uhg
area5:yutr
```

---

```
while read -r line

do 

grep -w ^line File2 | cut -d ":" -f2

done < File1
```

Desired output

---

```
aaaa
bbbb
hsg
```

actual output

---

```
grep: can't open a
area a
grep: cant open b

area3:abc
areaf:hsg
area4:uhg
area5:yutr
```

but when i run `grep -w ^"area a" File2 | cut -d ":" -f2` it is giving the correct output :

```
aaaa
```

Please assist me on this. i tried for loop also. no success. grep is not working inside loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `line` might contain "special characters". For example, a space that might be interpreted as a separator by the shell. Or some characters that might be interpreted as pattern metacharacter by grep.

You both need to use `fgrep` and to *quote* your variable (I'm not sure `-w` add anything to that command -- why do you feel the need of it?):

```
fgrep -w "$line"
```

But doing so you loose the ability to locate "the first character"

---

An other option if the "start of line" match is required is to *escape* the search string:

```
while read -r line
do 
    line=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')
    grep -w "^$line" File2 | cut -d ":" -f2
done < File1
```

Comment: while read -r line

do 

fgrep  "$line" File2 | cut -d ":" -f2

done < File1   ..... it worked. thank you very much.

Comment: @user3180371 Glad to have helped you. Remember than on SO you mostly say thank you by voting up and/or accepting answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result without a loop, since `grep` can read patterns from a file via the `-f` option. This will be more robust:

```
grep -f input1 input2 | cut -d: -f2
```

*Gives:*

```
aaaa
bbbb
hsg
```